# Android Fragment disappears after rendering

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an extremely strange issue that I am having a devil of a time working out.

I have a fragment that I am adding to a RelativeLayout (tried LinearLayout and FrameLayout too) that is dynamically populated with text content.

If the text content is too large, the fragment disappears after rendering. I have verified this by limiting the content length and it is fine in these cases.

This issue only seems to be happening on the Samsung Galaxy S4 that I have seen.

Is there a bug in the S4 system that restricts fragment heights when adding them to a View?

The code I am using to add the fragment is:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
mFragment = new DisplayFragment();
fragmentTransaction = fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.patient_container, mFragment, mFragment.getClass().getName());
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This code works on all devices that I have tested and all instances of the simulator except for the Galaxy S4. It only breaks on the S4 if the view height goes above a set limit (not sure what this is).

I am getting the following console warning when this issue happens:

> E/ViewSystem﹕ View #1 mHardwareLayer is not valid.

Any help on this would be extremely appreciated.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE: Added fragment XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/rootLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="top">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Patient's name:"
            style="@style/bodyText"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_text"
            android:id="@+id/patientsNameTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            style="@style/blueBodyText"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View style="@style/hr"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Patient's gender:"
            style="@style/bodyText"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_text"
            android:id="@+id/patientsGenderTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            style="@style/blueBodyText"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View style="@style/hr"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Patient&apos;s DOB:"
            style="@style/bodyText"
            android:id="@+id/patientsDOBTitle"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_text"
            android:id="@+id/patientsDOBTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            style="@style/blueBodyText"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View style="@style/hr"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Patient's telephone:"
            style="@style/bodyText"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:id="@+id/patientsTelephoneTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            style="@style/blueBodyText"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View style="@style/hr"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/horizontalLinearLayout"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:gravity="top">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Patient's postcode:"
            style="@style/bodyText"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:id="@+id/patientsPostcodeTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            style="@style/blueBodyText"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View style="@style/hr"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Patient's address:"
            style="@style/bodyText"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:id="@+id/patientsAddressTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            style="@style/blueBodyText"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View style="@style/hr"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Reason for referral:"
            style="@style/bodyText"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:id="@+id/referralReasonTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            style="@style/blueBodyText"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View style="@style/hr"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        style="@style/verticalLinearLayout">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Patient presenting with:"
            style="@style/bodyText"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/very_small_vertical_spacing"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:id="@+id/additionalInfoTextView"
            style="@style/blueBodyText"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_text"
            android:gravity="left"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View style="@style/hr"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Details of allergies:"
            style="@style/bodyText"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:id="@+id/allergiesTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            style="@style/blueBodyText"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View style="@style/hr"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Registered surgery:"
            style="@style/bodyText"
            android:id="@+id/registeredTextTitle"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:id="@+id/surgeryTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            style="@style/blueBodyText"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View style="@style/hr"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/small_vertical_spacing"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@color/grey_light_expanded"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/small_vertical_spacing"
        android:id="@+id/patientsBookingLocationHolder">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:id="@+id/patientsBookingLocationTextView"
            android:gravity="left"
            style="@style/boldBlueBodyText"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_text"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
    <View style="@style/hr"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"
          android:id="@+id/patientsBookingLocationHolderHR"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@color/grey_light_expanded">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Contact number:\n(at time of booking)"
            style="@style/bodyText"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:id="@+id/contactNumberTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            style="@style/blueBodyText"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View style="@style/hr"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@color/grey_light_expanded"
        android:id="@+id/patientRepHolder">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Patient's representative:"
            style="@style/bodyText"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:id="@+id/representativeTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            style="@style/blueBodyText"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View style="@style/hr"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"
          android:id="@+id/patientRepHolderHR"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:id="@+id/ambulanceRequiredHolder"
        android:background="@color/grey_light_expanded">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Ambulance required:"
            style="@style/bodyText"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:id="@+id/ambulanceRequiredTextView"
            android:gravity="right"
            style="@style/boldBlueBodyText"
            android:text="@string/placeholder_text"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View style="@style/hr"
          android:id="@+id/ambulanceRequiredHolderHR"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:id="@+id/patientsLocationHolder"
        android:background="@color/grey_light_expanded">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Patient's location at time of booking:"
            style="@style/bodyText"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Patient's name:"
            android:id="@+id/patientsLocationTextView"
            style="@style/blueBodyText"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_vertical_spacing"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View style="@style/hr"
          android:id="@+id/patientsLocationHolderHR"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="I confirm that:"
            style="@style/bodyText"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/small_vertical_spacing"
            android:gravity="left"
            style="@style/bodyText"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:id="@+id/confirmationText"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hmm, would be interesting to have a look at the fragment's layout.

Comment: I have added the XML file for the Fragment

Comment: What do you mean by text content is too large ? You have too many textviews or you have a textview which you fill with too long a text ? And how does it disappear ? The fragment is no longer in the stack or the view looks empty ?

Comment: @inmyth When I populate the text fields, if the accumulated height of all elements reaches a certain size the fragment simply goes invisible. It is as if the device cannot render the fragment. I have checked the layout in the Heirarchy tool and it is there, including all elements. The views are where they should be but they are just invisible.

Comment: Wow, that's the longest layout file ever. Are you trying to imitate some list view behaviour by manually creating so many rows? To my humble opinion, this design choice (huge number of views) is a mistake by itself, by solving which you can likely get rid of your main issue. `RecyclerView` and `ListView` were made specially for this, why not use them.

Comment: I went down the manual layout route as I have to place the list inside a scroll view with additional content. List views don't play nicely inside scroll views unless you calculate the total height of all rows and set the height of the list view, therefore eliminating the recycle pattern. As the number of fields is fixed, the manual layout works well.

Comment: Have you tried using a headerview or footerview on your list instead of hardcoding your list? Maybe try setting fillViewport="true" on your scrollview, or setting a maxLines on your textviews with a feature to expand the text when it's in focus. Could you post your DisplayFragment as well? How are you adding your text to it, perhaps you're performing some type of operation before your view has been properly inflated?

Comment: Hi @hhoang, It is a complicated layout that uses a list view on one side (which is expanded to match the height of the content) and then the fragment which I am having trouble with is added based on user input. The top half of the screen is a scrolling parallax header which sits outside the list view and fragment (crazy I know, but client's orders).

Comment: I know the layouts are inflating correctly as everything works fine if the populated content has less text (the difference between working and non working is about 10 lines worth of text across the whole layout). I think if I can work out what **E/ViewSystem﹕ View #1 mHardwareLayer is not valid.** means then we are on to a winner :)

Comment: Hmmm... random shot in the dark. maybe try disabling hardware acceleration for the activity? android:hardwareAccelerated="false", or try setting your layertype, view.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)?

Comment: I'll give that a try now and see what happens

Comment: @hhoang - Well that works / sort of. If I disable hardware acceleration programatically for the view then it fails but if I disable it for the whole app then it works. Which View should I be setting it on programatically? The container that I add the fragment too, the root view of the layout loaded by the fragment, or the view of the activity?

Comment: That's a damn good question. haha! I have no idea. I just saw HardwareLayer and figured it might be something with hardware acceleration. As for why that fixes it, your guess is as good as mine. I would think that you would set it on whatever you think is causing the Exception. Docs might help(http://goo.gl/TgtLtF) Or hopefully someone smarter can answer this question.

Comment: It has definitely get me started so thank you very much for that. Turning it off global works for the issue but performance is hit slightly on animations and some custom drawing elements seem to go funky so once I work out how to set it for my view without it breaking I think I am there with it :)

Comment: You can turn off the Hardware Acceleration for the view and immediate parent that should work.

Comment: "I went down the manual layout route as I have to place the list inside a scroll view with additional content. " ... does that mean you're not showing us the entire layout? Does the problem happen if it's in a scroll view? Also you use a lot of styles but we can't see them. Post the styles.